# Preset the value in the textfield tag inside a iterator loop?

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

It shows null value....... I changed struts-tags.tld file for textfield tag for value attribute return expression is set true....still unable to set the value....box is coming empty.please help...........

```
<s:iterator id="row" value="voList" status="stat">  
    <s:set name="flag" value="#stat.index" />   
    <s:set name="famt" value="#voList[${flag}].fromAmt"/>   
    <tr>
        <td class="tabcol" colspan="1">
            <s:property  value="#stat.index+1" />                   
        </td>   

        <td class="tabcol" colspan="1">
            <s:textfield theme="simple" size="5" maxlength="17"
                name="voList[${flag}].fromAmt" value="${famt}" 
                key="srvccharge.label.startRange" disabled="true"/>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

First: roll-back any change you made to the Struts Tag TLD.

Then use OGNL:

```
<s:iterator value="voList" status="ctr">
    <tr>
        <td class="tabcol">
            <s:property value="%{#ctr.count}" />
        </td>
        <td class="tabcol">
            <s:textfield theme="simple" 
                         name="voList[%{#ctr.index}].fromAmt" />
        </td>
```

P.S: `id` field is deprecated, use `var` instead; `colspan="1"` is the default, avoid putting it; key field can't differ from name (key = name+value+label); value is not necessary if the source is the same of name.